# running multiple loops simultaneosly

Tags: arduino, home-automation

I tried google, youtube, stackexchange but couldn't find a proper answer.
I am trying to design a home automation system with arduino which need to control a fan and a light. Simply activating a relay with arduino is not a thing, but here is the problem. I am controlling the speed of the fan also. So here is the basic code structure would look like.

if pin 1 is high

[

identify the zero crossing point of ac source;

add some delay to regulate the output power;

pulse it to the triac;

activate the relay related to fan;

]

if pin 2 is high

[

activate the relay related to light;

]

When the pin 1 is high the loop starts running and it stays inside the loop until the pin 1 is low. then it looks for pin 2's status[high or low].
So question is how do i control the light while the fan is in on condition. A lot of forums are suggesting timers but none with this kind of situation. If possible please give a minimum code, so i can start from that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things with a loop, then you need to change things around so the loop repeat is governed by the repeating synchronous mains cycle. This is not the cleanest way to do things, but it should be possible to get it to work.

Note there is only one slow thing to control, the phase-shift speed control of the fan. It can accomodate many other 'fast' things, read a switch, set a relay, within the time it takes to wait for the next zero crossing.

```
while running:
    {
    wait_for_zero_crossing();
    read_fan_speed_control();
    compute_speed_to_delay_for_fan();
    delay_for_fan_speed_control_time();
    pulse_fan_triac();

    set_fan_relay();    
    read_light_control();
    set_light_relay();    
    ...    
    read_other_control();
    set_other_relay();
    }
```

A rather better method is to use interrupts. Where you have a synchronous task like waiting for mains cycles, and an asynchronous task like reading switches, it is good to use interrupts to handle the timing critical part of the job, like this. Generally you want the interrupt service routine (ISR) to execute as quickly as possible, ie do as little work as possible. As long as a few cycles are spent outside the ISR, then your asynchronous code will run.

```
volatile int fan_control;      # needed so main and ISR communicate correctly

setup_ISR_to_run_every_100uS;  # for instance, 10kHz

while running:
    {
    read_fan_speed_control();
    fan_control = compute_speed_to_delay_for_fan();
    read_light_control();
    set_light_relay();
    ...
    read_other_control();
    set_other_relay();
    }

ISR:
    {
    if zero_crossing_just_happened():
        count = 0;
    else:
        count += 1;
    if count == fan_control:
        pulse_fan_triac();
    ...
    if count == other_control:
        pulse_other_triac();
    }
```

As you can see, it's easy to expand this ISR section to accommodate other phase shift control channels easily. I'll leave how to implement `zero_crossing_just_happened()` as an exercise for the reader.

These fragments are sketches, obviously much has been omitted. I've shown the `volatile` declaration as this is often forgotten in these situations. It forces the compiler to re-read the value from memory on every read, and not to try to optimise by using a register-based copy.

Once you've learnt to use interrupts, you can use them for things like scanning a multiplexed device, grabbing data from ADCs in the background, all sorts of things you can't do nicely with a single asynchronous loop.

Comment: ok let me check that.

Comment: QuickHelp @Neil_UK ; Obviously first one is not working properly. So lets move to the second one. Here in the 2nd line you asked me to run the 'ISR' function 10k times a second. Do you want me to call the 'ISR' function from 'running' loop or is it some thing else.

Comment: Ah ha....... eureka moment. Now i am controlling FAN(phase angle control) along with other on off type  controls at the same time. Thank you @Neil_UK. Your code helped me a lot. I didn't even use interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Arduino has a baked-in 'toybox' bias which, while allowing simple things to be done simply, scales poorly and really starts falling apart when you try to control more than one thing.

There are numerous ways to solve problems like this, including shuffling all your code solutions together into one monolithic mass, but one nice solution, if it works for you, is to use FreeRTOS to actually eliminate the usual Arduino 'only-one-thing' bias.  Each 'thing' you control is put in its own task, keeping the code separate.

Of course, there are some rules each task has to follow, in order not to interfere with the other tasks, but usually this is not too much of a hardship.

I once put together a multi-tasking Arduino prototype for a work project, that ultimately was abandoned, but it was looking very good up until then.  At least, so long as Ethernet was not included in the project!